# Use custom functions written in Python within a Databricks notebook

Tags: python, azure, databricks, egg

I have created a python file (.py) that includes two different functions.
For example,

```
def function1():
    print("Hello World")

def funtion2(a, b):
    y=a+b
    if y>=5:
        print("Correct")
    else:
        print("Wrong")
```

Now, I want to use those two functions in a Databricks Notebook. What I did, was to follow the steps written in this [databricks post](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8203/how-can-i-use-custom-modules-and-packages-i-write.html?childToView=38760#answer-38760). Even though I succeeded on creating an egg file that was later imported as a library in databricks I didn't manage to import my custom functions from the egg file. Please check the screenshots below:

**setup.py**

[image]

**egg file on Databricks**

[image]

When I try the python command:

```
import function2
```

I get an error that this module was not found. I appreciate any help and comments.
*Note: init.py file is not used*

Comment: Try "from python_functions.py import function2" or try " import python_function.py" then use function2.

Comment: @ZubadIbrahim Both ways you have written already gave me "No module named 'python_functions'". That's why I tried the .egg file approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following solution after some searching in the Web:

- 1. Create library notebook.

  > For example - `Lib` with any functions/classes there (no *runnable* code).
- 2. To import into `Main` all the classes and functions from `Lib` to `Main` use this command:

     ```
     %run "./Lib"
     ```

     (this will work like: from Lib import *)
- 3. After that you can call any functions / use classes that used in the `Lib` from `Main` notebook.

This is the [online post](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/17838/how-to-import-one-databricks-python-notebook-into.html) with the information.